# Accessing field annotations on Grails domain classes

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm trying to annotate fields over my domain classes but I'm not able to get them at runtime by reflection as usual Java fields.

My annotated domain class looks like:

```
class MyDomainClass {
    @MyAnnotation
    String myField
}
```

The Java way to access `myField` by reflection doesn't work:

```
MyDomainClass.class.getField("myField") //throws java.lang.NoSuchFieldException
```

The Grails way to inspect domain classes doesn't expose field annotations:

```
new DefaultGrailsDomainClass(MyDomainClass).getPersistentProperty("myField").??? //there is nothing similar to getAnnotations()
```

How can I retrieve the annotations associated with a domain field?

Comment: This [post](http://archives-mike.brevoort.com/2009/12/29/annotations-with-grails/index.html) uses delegate.class.declaredFields: `def theField = delegate.class.declaredFields.find{ field -> field.name == it.name}` and then `theField.isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation)` What is the magic?

Comment: I was also wondering why grails doesn't use annotations to set field specific info (default values, etc) and it leads me to suppose those annotations could not be retrieved at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a field, it's a property. When you declare a class-scope variable like that with no scope modifier (`public`, `protected`, etc.) in a Groovy class, the Groovy compiler converts it to a private field with the same type and name, and a getter and setter method, essentially

```
class MyDomainClass {
   @MyAnnotation
   private String myField

   public String getMyField() {
      return myField
   }
   public void setMyField(String s) {
      myField = s
   }
}
```

It won't overwrite an existing getter or setter though.

When you access the property you end up calling the getter or setter, which you can see if you add those methods and include `println` statements. This way Java classes can access the property via those methods, and Groovy pretends that you're directly reading or writing a field but under the hood you end up calling the same methods that you would from Java.

One benefit of this is that if you decide later that you want to add some logic when setting or getting the value, you can define the corresponding method(s) and add what you want without needing to change the code that accesses the property since in Groovy you can still treat it like a field and your custom methods will be called, and Java classes will have been calling the setter and getter all along.

`getFields()` returns only public fields, but `getDeclaredFields()` returns all of them, so since the actual field is private that's why `getDeclaredFields()` (or the property access form `declaredFields`) is necessary.

Grails doesn't use annotations because Graeme (and others) feel that they're ugly and bulky, not because they're not accessible.

Comment: GREAT. Work like a charm.

Comment: Regarding Graeme concerns, I understand annotations are not a consensus, but I myself find it an excellent tool to retain maintainability and I'm thinking about overriding grails default behavior to supply property related info. And if anyone else find it useful, I'll try and make it as a plugin. Have you heard such requests?